# prediction interval from gls model with corAR1 or corARMA

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, autocorrelation, prediction-interval, generalized-least-squares

In R using the nlme package, how can I compute a prediction interval for a gls model with a corARMA or corAR1 correlation structure?
For instance :

```
data("airquality")
require(nlme)
g1<-gls(data = airquality, Ozone~Temp, correlation = corARMA(p=1, q=1), na.action = na.omit)
summary(g1)
newdata<-data.frame(Temp=c(0:100))
pred<-predict(g1, newdata=newdata)
```